# Shifting of the blocks of question views on ru.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, design, russian-stackoverflow

There is a problem with rendering of questions page for 100% zoom on ru.stackoverflow.com ([Source](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2811/%D0%A1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0))

Web-browsers:

- Mozilla Iceweasel 38.7.1
- Mozilla Firefox 45.3.0

[image]